# how to view decoded messagepack data in redis-cli

Tags: redis, msgpack, redis-cli

i have data stored in redis in messagepack. How to view the data decoded in redis-cli.

I don't see any commands related to it.

Comment: redis LUA has `http://redis.io/commands/EVAL` seach for `cmsgpack`. Also, http://fperrad.github.io/lua-MessagePack/msgpack.html#examples may be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

redis-cli has no pretty-print functionality (yet). However, as **@Ryan Vincent** had suggested, you can use a Redis Lua script for that purpose. Assuming that your MessagePack-ed data is stored in the String key called `foo`, this would do your bidding:

```
EVAL "return cmsgpack.unpack(redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]))" 1 foo
```

**EDIT:** the above assumes that the data is serialized as arrays. Returning an object will not work as Redis' protocol doesn't support that.